# Python Min/Max Dates with Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the start and end dates for particular price. In my example, the price is $3 for few days, then increases to $4 for few days and back to $3 later on.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"Price":3,"ds":"2017-01-01"},
    {"Price":3,"ds":"2017-01-02"},
    {"Price":3,"ds":"2017-01-03"},
    {"Price":3,"ds":"2017-01-04"},
    {"Price":3,"ds":"2017-01-05"},
    {"Price":4,"ds":"2017-01-06"},
    {"Price":4,"ds":"2017-01-07"},
    {"Price":4,"ds":"2017-01-08"},
    {"Price":4,"ds":"2017-01-09"},
    {"Price":3,"ds":"2017-01-10"},
    {"Price":3,"ds":"2017-01-11"},
    {"Price":3,"ds":"2017-01-12"},
    {"Price":3,"ds":"2017-01-13"},
    {"Price":3,"ds":"2017-01-14"}
    ])

start = df.groupby(["Price"])["ds"].min().reset_index()
end = df.groupby(["Price"])["ds"].max().reset_index()
df2 = start.merge(end, how = 'left', on = ["Price"])
df2.rename(columns = {"ds_x":"start_dt", "ds_y":"end_dt"},inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   Price start_dt    end_dt
     3  2017-01-01  2017-01-14
     4  2017-01-06  2017-01-09
```

Desired Output:

```
   Price start_dt    end_dt
     3  2017-01-01  2017-01-05
     4  2017-01-06  2017-01-09
     3  2017-01-10  2017-01-14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from your original dataframe , you can use a helper column with `series.shift` to compare the next row and use it for grouping, then groupby and agg with min and max, rename and reset the index:

```
s = df['Price'].ne(df['Price'].shift()).cumsum()

d = {"min":"start_dt", "max":"end_dt"}
out = (df.groupby([s,'Price'])['ds'].agg(['min','max']).rename(columns=d)
                                             .droplevel(0).reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)

   Price    start_dt      end_dt
0      3  2017-01-01  2017-01-05
1      4  2017-01-06  2017-01-09
2      3  2017-01-10  2017-01-14
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. One more Q. The above method does not work when there is one more categorical variable. I tried groupby but it does not have 'ne'. df.groupby(["Item"])['Price'].ne(df.groupby(["Item"])['Price'].shift()).cumsum(). any thoughts?

Comment: @appdev1014 include them when shifting to compare to the next row, assuming the column is named as `Col1` it would look something like `s = df[['Price','Col1']].ne(df[['Price','Col1']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()` , replace `any(axis=1)` with `all(axis=1)` depending on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. could you explain the need for any/all (axis=1)?